# To create two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

Guys can any one help me to do this code because i used 6hours and still don't get the answer.

The question is " write a program that creates a two-dimensional array(6*6),populate the array with random numbers between 1 and 100.
a:Get the total of all numbers
b:Get the average of all numbers
c:Determine the row total
d:Determine the highest in the row
e:Determine the lowest in the row

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// Main Function
int main()
{
    //Initialize Variables
    int table1[6][6];
    int highest ;
    int lowest ;
    double sumRow = 0;

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    //PrintArray
    for (row = 0; row < 6; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < 6; col++)
        {
            {
                table1[row][col] = rand() % 100 + 1;
            }
            cout << table1[row][col] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "" << endl << endl;
    }

    //Highest & lowest value in the row
    for( row = 0; row <6; row ++)
    {    
        highest = table1[row][0];
        lowest = table1[row][0];

        for ( col = 0; col < 6; col++)
        {
            if ( highest < table1[row][col])
                highest = table1[row][col];
            if  (lowest > table1[row][col])
                lowest = table1[row][col];
            sumRow = sumRow + table1[row][col];

        }
        cout <<" Row" << row <<" highest value :" << highest <<endl;
        cout <<" Row" << row <<" lowest value  :" << lowest  << endl;
        cout <<" Row" << row <<" average value :" << sumRow/6 <<endl;
        cout <<" Row" << row <<" Total value   :" << sumRow  << endl;
        sumRow = 0;

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"[I] still don't get the answer"_ isn't a particularly good problem description. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: @ItsGreg `row = 0` and `col=0` in loops doing this, I think

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a possible solution. Please use this as a reference to determine your code's issues.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int table[6][6];
  int row_total[6];
  int row_max[6];
  int row_min[6];
  int total_total = 0;

  srand(time(NULL));

  for( int row = 0 ; row < 6 ; row++ ) {
    row_total[row] = 0;
    row_max[row] = numeric_limits<int>::min();
    row_min[row] = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for( int col = 0 ; col < 6 ; col++ ) {
      table[row][col] = rand() % 100 + 1;
      row_total[row] += table[row][col];
      row_max[row] = max(table[row][col],row_max[row]);
      row_min[row] = min(table[row][col],row_min[row]);
    }
    total_total += row_total[row];
  }

  for( int row = 0 ; row < 6 ; row++ ){
    for( int col = 0 ; col < 6 ; col++ ){
      cout << std::right << std::setw(4) << table[row][col];
    }
    cout << "\tTotal: " << std::right << std::setw(4) << row_total[row];
    cout << "\tMax: " << std::right << std::setw(4) << row_max[row];
    cout << "\tMin: " << std::right << std::setw(4) << row_min[row] <<      std::endl;
  }

  cout << "Total of all numbers: " << total_total << std::endl;
  cout << "Average of all numbers: "
    << setiosflags(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint)
    << setprecision(2)
    << total_total/36.0 << std::endl;
}
```